# How to simplify this oracle sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have written following select to get the previous different grade value from jobs table.
This works well but is it possible to simplify the code that it won't have 3 levels?

```
    select value_1 
      from ( select distinct 
                    value_1,
                    date_from,
                    date_to,
                    emp_id,
                    (select o.value_1 
                      from jobs o
                      where o.emp_id=w.emp_id 
                        and (
                              (o.date_to >= sysdate and o.date_from <= sysdate) or
                              (o.data_from <= sysdate and o.data_to is null)
                             )
                      ) current_grade
           from jobs w
          where w.emp_id = t.emp_id 
          order by data_from desc
           )
    where value_1 != current_grade 
      and data_from <= sysdate 
      and rownum=1 
      and t.emp_id=123 
    order by data_from desc, 
             value_1, 
             emp_id
```

What it suppose to do? I want to select previous different grade value from jobs table. This table is used to store positions for each employee, they have date_from, date_to, additionally in value_1 we store the grade symbol. What is important for me is to select previous different value for grade which could have changed 3 positions before.

Comment: Please show us your table definitions.

Comment: Better yet sample of data and desired output.

Comment: Two things I see wrong: 1) `date_from<=sysdate and date_from is null` is bad. A value can't be <= something *and* null, so this condition will never be met. 2) Using `order by` with `rownum=1` is meaningless; you will get the first row of the result set in whatever order it was generated in -- the order by will not do anything

Comment: Can you describe what this is supposed to do?

Comment: I have corrected error noticed by Gordon in 1st point.

Comment: where w.emp_id = t.emp_id 

I don't see any table with an alias "t" in your query

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get away from a three-level query in this instance, but it can be simplified.  As I noted in my comment, the ORDER BY in the outer query is superfluous, and you would actually get incorrect results if the ORDER BY in the **second** query was not there.  Oracle's rownum does not work like other databases' Top-N queries -- rownum is calculated **before** order by, so using `rownum=` with an ORDER BY will not necessarily return the highest row.

This should produce the desired result, and is slightly more compact:

```
SELECT
    value_1
FROM
(
    SELECT
        value_1
    FROM
        jobs w
    WHERE
        date_from <= sysdate
        and emp_id=123
        and value_1 != (SELECT value_1
                          FROM jobs o
                         WHERE o.emp_id = w.emp_id
                                AND (o.date_to >= sysdate and o.date_from <= sysdate
                                     OR o.date_from <= sysdate and o.date_to is null))
    ORDER BY date_from desc                  
)
WHERE
    rownum = 1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0dad8/22/0)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a single table hit by getting value_1 of latest date_to value in the past.

```
select value_1 from jobs where date_to < sysdate and emp_id = 123
```

If you need the latest job role do a order by desc and get first row.

Comment: Try it out before downvoting. Instead of checking date_to is null or >= sysdate and joing again with same table. Go in different direction to get the same result.